# Update Wishlist Item in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to update a particular item in wishlist programmatically. I have a configurable product in my wishlist and i need to update the values of the wishlist item options (Size, Color) via ajax. I have tried using the following piece of code but throwing exception as "Cannot specify wishlist item."

```
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
$params = array(
'id' => 7,
'qty' => 1,
'product' => 123,
'super_attribute' => array('525' => '100')
);
try{
    $wishlist->updateItem(7, null, $params);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

Comment: `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist::updateItem()` requires the wishlist to be loaded (to have an ID) and the item updated should belong to the wishlist.


It is your responsibility to implement a proper authorization to make sure only authorized actors can modify a wishlist.